# Get whole object data instead id in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have an object with this structure, that I need to get name of source_id in my blade file,
When I try to access that by the way

> $data['source_id']['name']

> $data->source_id->name

> $data->{'source_id'}->{'name'}

I got this error

> > **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**
> > I just try `this $data->source_id`, but it return its ID, instead the object,
> > any suggestion?

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "type": "s1",
  "source_id": {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "۱",
    "name": "تیل پطرول",
    "manager": "نجیب",
    "phone": "۰۷۷۲۴۳۴۳۲۱",
    "address": "دهمزنگ",
    "capacity": "0.00",
    "oum_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-03-02T15:55:20.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-02T15:55:20.000000Z"
  },
  "source_type": "STRG",
}
```

Here is the function to get data

```
public function loadSale($id){
  $base = Sale::findOrFail($id);
    if ($base->type == "s1") {
      $sale = Sale::with(['saleS1.project.pro_data', 'source_id'])->where('id', $id)->first();
      $sale['sales'] = $sale->saleS1;
    }
  return $sale
}
```

Comment: does your relation named as source_id, if not then use the relation name as `$data->[relation_name]->name`. Or there might be some issue between `data` and `source` relation

Comment: can you please tell us how you get this $data object in the first place? I know that you've sent it to your blade view using `return view('view_name', ['data' => $some_data]);`. I want to know how you got that `$some_data` object

Comment: updated, and the relation is the same name as source_id

Comment: I guess the name of your relation and foreign key field is same, that's why you get `id` when you do this `$data->source_id`

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem, I use source and now its working fine. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I could understand your problem. But it is an object not an array. You have to use a loop to access the object. Create a for loop and and inside which you can access the particular field of the object. Hope this helpful

Comment: @MAY comment is the answer

Answer (score 0):

As @MAY mentioned in the comment

> I guess **the name of your relation and foreign key field is same**, that's why you get id when you do this `$data->source_id`

So I modify the relation and define the `source`, now I can't access the data simply as before `$data->source->name`